# How to customize search result page title?

Tags: functions, customization, templates, search, title

I would like to customize the page title of the search result page:

from:

```
<title>Search Results for “search string” – Page 2 – Sitename</title>
```

to:

```
<title>“search string” result page – Page 2 – Sitename</title>
```

In my search.php template, `get_header()` is probably the one being called to generate the `<title>` tag.

Is there a filter that I can apply to it to make this customization?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Within the `wp_get_document_title()` function we have:

```
// If it's a search, use a dynamic search results title.
} elseif ( is_search() ) {
        /* translators: %s: search phrase */
        $title['title'] = sprintf( 
            __( 'Search Results for &#8220;%s&#8221;' ), 
            get_search_query() 
        );
```

so you could hook into the `document_title_parts` filter to adjust it to your neds.

**Example:**

```
/**
 * Modify the document title for the search page
 */
add_filter( 'document_title_parts', function( $title )
{
    if ( is_search() ) 
        $title['title'] = sprintf( 
            esc_html__( '&#8220;%s&#8221; result page', 'my-theme-domain' ), 
            get_search_query() 
        );

    return $title;
} );
```

**Note:** This assumes your theme supports `title-tag`.

**Update:**

> Can I also customize the Page 2 part of the title in the same filter?

Regarding the *page* part, you can adjust it in a similar way with:

```
/**
 * Modify the page part of the document title for the search page
 */
add_filter( 'document_title_parts', function( $title ) use( &$page, &$paged )
{
    if ( is_search() && ( $paged >= 2 || $page >= 2 ) && ! is_404() ) 
        $title['page'] = sprintf( 
            esc_html__( 'This is %s page', 'my-theme-domain' ), 
            max( $paged, $page ) 
        );

    return $title;
} );
```

Comment: Works perfect.  One question, I tried to change the domain parameter to my 'child theme slug', 'parent theme slug', and even remove the parameter, they all work.  What would be an example of use for the domain parameter in practice?  Thanks.

Comment: An extended question to this, instead of asking another question.  Can I also customize the `Page 2` part of the title in the same filter?  Making it `This is 2 page`, which may not make sense in plain English, but I'm customizing it into a non-english grammar.

Comment: Answering my own extended question in the comment. Modifying the `return` statement to the following will do the trick:
`return preg_replace('/Page (\d+)/', 'This is $1 page', $title);`

Comment: I added an example for the *page* part. I added the *domain*, since the strings are most likely not availabe in the core translation, so it's up to you to translate it. @KDX