# How to change tab's title in search results pages?

Tags: search, title

I succeeded in changing the "Results for:" part above the search results, but I can't seem to find how to change the text of the title of the page which is displayed in the tab of the browser. Sadly, it's still the stock 'Search Results for "X"', like so:

[image]

I also would like to change the 'Nothing Found' page text, but can't seem to find where this is located.

Finally, I can't seem to find how to change the 'Continue Reading'. It's different from the 'Read More...' mentioned in the WordPress documentation.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to customize search result page title?](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/225724/how-to-customize-search-result-page-title)

Answer (score 0):

You have to hook into the **[document_title_parts](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/hooks/document_title_parts/)** filter to adjust it to your needs.

**Example:**

```
/**
 * Modify the document title for the search page
 */
add_filter( 'document_title_parts', function( $title )
{
    if ( is_search() ) 
        $title['title'] = sprintf( 
            esc_html__( '&#8220;%s&#8221; result page', 'my-theme-domain' ), 
            get_search_query() 
        );

    return $title;
} );
```

For Multiple paged search page you have to do like this:

```
/**
 * Modify the page part of the document title for the search page
 */
add_filter( 'document_title_parts', function( $title ) use( &$page, &$paged )
{
    if ( is_search() && ( $paged >= 2 || $page >= 2 ) && ! is_404() ) 
        $title['page'] = sprintf( 
            esc_html__( 'This is %s page', 'my-theme-domain' ), 
            max( $paged, $page ) 
        );

    return $title;
} );
```

modify the example I gave according to your need.

**title-tag** must be supported by your theme.

Comment: These examples look familiar from my answer [here](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/a/225734/26350)

Comment: Yes it's the same. Here I copy paste the code from my collection of snippets. It seems this one i collected from your answer. Thanks for mentioning the url. Going to edit and add reference.

Comment: glad to hear you found it useful, cheers